# Passing a c++ double buffer to Node Js (directly) [Node JS : V8 c++ : Nan]

Tags: c++, node.js, pointers, v8, node.js-addon

I'm trying to pass a determined array of doubles from c++ back to Node JS. The way I'm doing it right now works but it kill performance. Because I need to convert the double buffer to a v8 array. Is There a way to directly pass the doubles to node JS without converting? Here is a pseudo convertion code I wish to avoid to use:

```
NAN_METHOD(getDoubles) {
    NanScope();

    .... calculate double array named:  double *VALS;
    .... collected elsewhere in my source. Then:

    int  len=6;
    Local<Array>  ARRAY  = NanNew<Array>(len);
    Local<Object> PARAMS = NanNew<Object>();
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)   {
      ARRAY->Set(i, NanNew<Number>(VALS[i]));
    }       
    PARAMS->Set(NanNew<String>("values"), ARRAY);
    NanReturnValue(PARAMS);
}
```

from node js, I get back the doubles like this:

```
var addon = require("mycpp_addon");
var result = addon.getDoubles();
console.log(result.values);
```

Comment: Please realize that if that double array is local, when the function returns, the array becomes invalid.  So passing pointers to local variables will not work, unless the array is dynamically allocated in some way and is not deallocated when the function returns.  I don't know `node.js` but probably that's why the example you posted does it in this way -- it ensures that there is no chance of holding onto remnants of a local array that will become invalidated before `node.js` uses it.

Comment: I suppose now that this cannot be done, Because each part has its own memory mechanism. So I think this question can be closed

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass large data, you should use the [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) class.

On [this page](http://luismreis.github.io/node-bindings-guide/docs/returning.html) you can get an example of usage near the bottom.

This way you can pass a block of memory back into javascript without any copy taking place.